# Creating custom Built in Intents for App Actions

Tags: android, actions-on-google, app-actions

There is a list of Built-in Intents available that can be used in App Actions on the [Google Developers website](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/built-in-intents/), is there any way we can create our custom Built-in Intents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible to create custom built-in intents for App Actions. As per the [App Actions docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/bii-integrations):

> If these built-in intents do not support your use case, please file a feature request on the [public issues tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=617864&template=1261453)

As a side note, while not custom, there is a more generic "[open app feature](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/bii-integrations#open_app_feature)" (`actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE`) built-in intent that might work for some use-cases.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. I want to use actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE to open a specific activity of my app, here i couldn't understand how i can specify this in the fields for this intent. In documents, it is written that it supports "feature" as field. How can we pass our deeplink in this feature?

Comment: The activity (target) that you want to open is specified as a deep link in the `urlTemplate` field. To set it up, see the docs (step1/2): https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/quickstart#deeplink

The "feature" is some name of the screen/feature the user gives in when they ask for your app. The value will be passed through to your app.

Comment: @AdamK did you manage with OPEN_APP_FEATURE? It works for me in App Actions Test Tools but not from phone.
There is even a Google issue about this:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135714718

Comment: @rosualin I haven't tested myself. I will ask for someone to check on status and update the issue.