# Creating custom app actions for android application

Tags: android, app-actions

Hi I have integrated some of predefine app actions like "**actions.intent.CREATE_TAXI_RESERVATION**". Now I want to create some custom intents. I checked with creating custom intents on dialog flow. But how to consume those on android applications side. and how to use them in Androids **actions.xml**. Is there any structured document to do so?

Comment: I am not sure about your requirement exactly. Do you want to know how the another app will call this action? If so then the answer will be exactly how you can any action such as call or message using BroadcastReceiver. Confirm your requierment in detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating custom Built in Intents for App Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56555424/creating-custom-built-in-intents-for-app-actions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556518/268156